# How to populate a variable/expression in CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy, cvx

I am trying to translate cvx code to cvxpy. The major problem I am having is finding something similar to expressions. I used expressions to set values for an entire list of len(n). From my understanding the attributes in a variable in cvx cannot be modified while an expression can. In cvx I would do this by:

```
n = 100;
init = 10;
cvx begin 
   variables A(n), B(n), C(n)
   expression X(n)
   X(1) = init;
   for t=2:n
       X(t) = X(t - 1) + A(t - 1) + B(t - 1) + C(t - 1)
   end

   minimize(sum(A) + max(B))
   subject to 
     for t = 1:n
       A(t) >= 1;
       B(t) <= 1;
       C(t) >= 1;
     end
cvx end
```

According to a previous post([How to set cvxpy n-dim variable first value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62299396/how-to-set-cvxpy-n-dim-variable-first-value))there seems to be no equivalent to expressions in cvxpy afaik, so I would need to create that variable to a constraint like so.

```
   import cvxpy as cp
   n = 100
   init = 10
   A = cp.variable(n)
   B = cp.variable(n)
   C = cp.variable(n)
   X = cp.variable(n)
   
   obj = cp.Minimize(sum(A) + max(B))
   # TODO automate introduction of variables.
   cons = [
      X[0] == init,
      A[0] >= 1,
      B[0] <= 1,
      C[0] >= 1
   ]

   cons2 = [
      X[t] == X[t - 1] + A[t - 1] + B[t - 1] + C[t - 1],
      A[t] >= 1,
      B[t] <= 1,
      C[t] >= 1
      for t in range(1,n)
   ]
   cons.append(cons2)
   prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)
```

I get this error message: "NotImplementedError: Strict inequalities are not allowed." Apparently cvxpy does not like == in the constraints, but I am not sure how to populate X otherwise. Also, I think I might be off with my list creation for the constraints as well. Thank you for the help.

Alternate cvxpy code:

```
   import cvxpy as cp
   n = 100
   init = 10
   A = cp.variable(n)
   B = cp.variable(n)
   C = cp.variable(n)
   X = cp.variable(n)
   
   obj = cp.Minimize(sum(A) + max(B))
   # TODO automate introduction of variables.
   cons = [
      X[0] == init,
      A[0] >= 1,
      B[0] <= 1,
      C[0] >= 1
   ]

   for t in range(1,n)
      cons2 = [
          X[t] == X[t - 1] + A[t - 1] + B[t - 1] + C[t - 1],
          A[t] >= 1,
          B[t] <= 1,
          C[t] >= 1
      ]
      cons.append(cons2)
   prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also don't know how to translate expression of cvx to cvxpy, nor do I know how to solve your optimization problem with cvxpy. However, I can provide fixes to your code sample so that no errors are raised.

##### Fix 1:

> I get this error message: "NotImplementedError: Strict inequalities are not allowed." Apparently cvxpy does not like == in the constraints, but I am not sure how to populate X otherwise.

This error is actually caused by calling the wrong `sum` and `max` function. You have to call the functions of cvxpy module, which can take the Variable Expression of cvxpy as input. So the proper way would be `cp.sum(A) + cp.max(B)`.

##### Fix 2:

> Also, I think I might be off with my list creation for the constraints as well. Thank you for the help.

1. In your first cvxpy code sample: the list comprehension syntax provided to create list `cons2` seems to be wrong and is not applicable like that. I don't know if there is an elegant way to use list comprehension for that specific creation.
2. In your alternate cvxpy code sample: `cons.append(cons2)` would actually append the list `cons2` into `cons` instead of the elements contained in the list `cons2`. What you want is to combine those 2 lists and this can be easily achieved with following syntax: `cons += cons2`.

##### Fix 3:

1. Wrong spelling: `cp.variable(n)` should be `cp.Variable(n)` instead.

#### Fixed cvxpy code:

```py
import cvxpy as cp
n = 100
init = 10
A = cp.Variable(n)
B = cp.Variable(n)
C = cp.Variable(n)
X = cp.Variable(n)

obj = cp.Minimize(cp.sum(A) + cp.max(B))
# TODO automate introduction of variables.
cons = [
   X[0] == init,
   A[0] >= 1,
   B[0] <= 1,
   C[0] >= 1
]

for t in range(1,n):
    cons2 = [
        X[t] == X[t - 1] + A[t - 1] + B[t - 1] + C[t - 1],
        A[t] >= 1,
        B[t] <= 1,
        C[t] >= 1
    ]
    cons += cons2
prob = cp.Problem(obj, cons)

print(prob.solve(solver=cp.SCS))
print(prob.status)
```